# Oracle SQL select with different data for each run, using Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make a query or a plsql that can give me an ID of a table using 2 table data but I want to change the data on each run

I mean, this is what i have

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT ID_EMP FROM EMPLOYES WHERE NAME_EMP = 'data' AND LASNAME_EMP = 'data2')
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('EMPLOYE ID ' || c.ID_EMP);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

But I want to change "data" and "data2" for each run, perhaps using something like a list where the query takes "data" and "data2"

There is a way?
Thanks

Comment: What is meant by `want to change "data" and "data2"`

Comment: Do you want to create a procedure and pass in NAME_EMP and LASNAME_EMP as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the given anonymous block as is, you can just put '&' in front of your input fields as shown below. It will always ask for your inputs before run.
Otherwise you should write a procedure with two input parameters (`first_name` and `last_name`), and call the procedure as many times as you want.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT ID_EMP FROM EMPLOYES WHERE NAME_EMP = '&data' AND LASNAME_EMP = '&data2')
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('EMPLOYE ID ' || c.ID_EMP);
        END LOOP;
END;
```